# Socket.io is not able to send packets

Tags: websocket, socket.io

i am trying to send a packet to the client when it connects.
 for server side i have used Socket.io with OSGI and Karaf.
and i am sending it as

server.addConnectListener(new ConnectListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onConnect(SocketIOClient client) {
       log.info("A new client has connected -> {}", client.getSessionId());
          int count = 1;
        boolean count1 = true;
        StringBuffer builder = new StringBuffer();
        for(int i=0; i < 5; i++) { builder.append("A"); }
        Packet packet = new Packet(PacketType.EVENT);
        packet.setName("trader");
        ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
        arr.add(builder.toString());
        packet.setData(arr);
        System.out.println("sending data " + arr);
        client.send(packet);
   }
    });
```

and the client i am accessing it as

```
   <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js'></script>
   <script src='https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.1.0.js'></script>
   <script>
       var socket = io.connect('ws://localhost:8807');
       socket.on('connect', function(data) {
       debugger;
       console.log("connected");

       });
       socket.on('time', function(data) {
           console.log(data);
           $('#messages').append('<li>' + data.time + '</li>');
       });
       socket.on('trader', function(data){

       console.log("recieving data");
        $('#messages').append('<li>' + data + '</li>');
       });
       socket.on('Message', function(data){

       console.log("recieving data");
        $('#messages').append('<li>' + data + '</li>');
       });
       socket.on('error', function(data) {
       debugger;
       console.error(arguments)
       });
   </script>
```

i am getting the error as 
message: "xhr poll error", type : type: "TransportError"